# What does Query Projection mean in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking at some EF examples and trying to decipher what 'Query Projection' *exactly* equates to when doing LINQ to Entities or EntitySQL. I believe it is when the query results are filtered and projected into an anonymous type but not 100% sure.

Can someone please define this and maybe provide a small L2E query that uses an example of it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Projection is when the result of a query is output to a different type than the one queried.     [Another article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqProjection.aspx) defined it as : *the process of transforming the results of a query*

Projection can be to an anonymous type, but could also be to a concrete type. If you come from a SQL world, it is akin to the columns listed in your `SELECT` clause.

**Example selecting a sub-set of an object into an concrete type:**

```
ParentObj.Select(x=> new ParentSlim { ParentID = x.ParentID,  Name = x.Name } );
```

.
**Example merging to object into a 3rd anonymous type:**
   *Note: the `select new` portion is the projection.*

```
from P in ParentObj.AsQueryable()
join C in ChildObj.AsQueryable() on P.ParentID == C.ParentID

select new {                              // <-- look ma, i'm projecting!
               ParentID = P.ParentID,
               Name     = P.Name,
               SubName  = C.Name
               RandomDate = DateTime.UtcNow()
         }
```

Comment: Agreed, I enjoy that guys writing.

Comment: @EBarr: Query projection can improve indexing on sql server? how?

Comment: @Amir - where did I say that?  I do see how it could result in faster executions under certain circumstances.  If, however, you have distinct question it's best to post a question and allow people to fully respond.