# Query returns all results quickly, but then when call to JSON times out due to loading all unnecessary properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, json.net

I have the following query that gets a list of schools based on the criteria provided. Note: This database is very, very large with 10,000+ records. The end result is a list of 188 schools, which is exactly as we need.

```
return (from s in Context.Schools
        join d in Context.Districts on s.DistrictID equals d.DistrictID
        join r in Context.Rosters on s.SchoolID equals r.SchoolID
        join te in Context.TestEvents on r.TestEventID equals te.TestEventID
        join ta in Context.TestAdministrations on te.TestAdministrationID equals ta.TestAdministrationID
        join sr in Context.ScoreResults on r.RosterID equals sr.RosterID into exists
        from any in exists.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where d.DistrictID == DistrictID
        && ta.SchoolYearID == SchoolYearID.Value
        select s)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();
```

The problem is when we call `return Json(Schools, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to send our schools back to the client the operation times out. It appears when stepping thorough the code that for some reason the DbContext is trying to pull in ALL of the properties for this result set, including the ones we don't need. I already have everything I need from the database in this `Schools` object. Why does it go back and start creating all the associated objects. Is there a way to stop this?.

This is an MVC application using EF 5 Code First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting the whole entity, select a projection of only what you need:

```
var results = from s in Context.Schools
    ...
    select new MyClassContainingOnlyAFewProperties {
                 Prop1 = s.Prop1,
                 Prop2 = s.Prop2, 
                 //etc.
    }
return results;
```

See also: [What does Query Projection mean in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857655/what-does-query-projection-mean-in-entity-framework)