# create entity with specific list of columns using Entity Framework 5

Tags: performance, entity-framework-5

I've got SQL tables with 100 columns and I've created model for that table.

I am using repositories to query table and I want specific columns (e.g only 10 columns) in my select statement to improve performance.

When I run SQL Server Profiler I can see it select all columns and I ant to avoid that.

Is there any way when DataContext try to query table then it uses entity with specific columns only?

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning entities, they have to be fully-populated with data.  If you need to get only certain pieces of data, use a [projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857655/what-does-query-projection-mean-in-entity-framework).

Comment: Thanks for reply. what I am looking for is.. I've entity called Customer and I've lite entity CustomerLite.  Now when I call Select statement using DBContext is it possible to use columns from CustomerLite entity?

Comment: Last I knew, EF would not let you map two entities to the same table.  Why is it you want to do so, and not use projections?

Comment: I've look up table with 300 columns (data imported from DB2) and I only want to use 20 columns in my app.  I am using repositories to get data. Instead of changing table structure I was thinking I can I create entity with 20 columns but still uses same DB table (with 300 columns) as no of columns in select affects performance and in batch process times adds up. one way I thought can use view with limited columns but that increases no of DBO.