# Selecting fields from different table

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 tables. Order, Orderlines and Stores. In Order table has StoreId which is a foreign key from Stores table and In Orderlines table has OrderId a foreign key from Order table. I only need to get the fields Order.OrderId, Order.WarehouseOrderId, Store.StoreName and the count of Orderlines per Order. So currently this is my implementation:

```
public List<Order> GetOrdersDashboardWithoutStatus1(SearchDashboardCriteria cri)
{
    using (var ctx = CreateDbContext())
    {
        var orders = (from items in ctx.Orders select items);
        if (cri.MerchantId != 0)
        {
            orders = orders.Where(x => x.Store.MerchantId == cri.MerchantId);
        }

        return orders.Where(x => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateImported) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(cri.StartDate))
                && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateImported) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(cri.EndDate)))
                 .Include(x => x.Store).Include(x => x.OrderLines).ToList();
    }
}
```

Through the currently implementation is working but the performance is very slow and sometimes it gets a Time Out error because a records may have 30K+ orders.

Comment: you can use [Linq Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) for this. you can use something like:`var _storeOrders = ctx.Orders.Join(ctx.Store,od=>od.StoreId,st=>st.StoreId,(od,st)=>{_orders=od,_stores=st}).Where(w=>w._stores.MerchantId==cri.MerchantId).ToList()` to get all the `orders+store` info related to the `merchantId` and  later use this variable to join with `OrderLines` and get the appropriate result.

Comment: please include your model into the question. You could try anonymous projection which will only return columns that you need rather than including all data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
using (var ctx = CreateDbContext())
{
            var orders = (from x in ctx.Orders 
                          where x.Store.MerchantId == cri.MerchantId
                          && add your other where condition
                          select NewDataModel
                          {
                            orderId = x.OrderId,
                            wareHouse = x.WarehouseOrderId,
                            storeName = x.Store.StoreName
                          }).ToArray();

}
```

Anonymous projection or projection to your custom model only retrieve columns that are included in the projection.

Instead of `Select * from Orders ...` it will be `Select OrderId,WareHouseOrderId from Orders`

you can also try for paging `(Take,skip)` if your use case support it.
[Similar answer for anonymous projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857655/what-does-query-projection-mean-in-entity-framework)